# Can gravity control be scaled?

Tags: space-travel, gravity

"If we have artificial gravity on a ship(Enterprise style), would't we have the ability to create other gravity based technologies like folding space for distant travel?"

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: This seems to be a particular case of [What factors could lead to a narrow focus of technology?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/406/what-factors-could-lead-to-a-narrow-focus-of-technology)

Comment: This doesn't even seem like a proper question.

Comment: See [this Answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53422/why-arent-complex-devices-or-electronics-ever-built-out-of-force-fields-in-scie/53427#53427). Same answer exactly.  (That Q was also closed, BTW.)

Comment: (continued) this question http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52327/how-far-can-space-time-be-warped-twisted-and-pulled?rq=1 Sorry if this isn't friendliest welcome to Worldbuilding SE, but it's an art in asking the right questions here. Your question has the core of an interesting idea, it just has to be framed in form that answers can be given proper form. Don't be discouraged. I hope to see more questions & answers from you.

Comment: Hi Barry, weirdly enough this comment was originally the predecessor of this one. Another question related to yours is this one: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41074/weird-shennanigans-with-artificial-gravity?rq=1 Hope they're useful.

Comment: No problem, I see what I did there. Also, I was having trouble navigating, but I think I figured it out. The question is, "If we have artificial gravity on a ship, would't we have the ability to create other gravity based technologies like folding space for distant travel?" Thanks everyone who answered, I'll get this figured out.

Comment: @a4android, thanks for the articles. They definitely help focus my thoughts. The answer seems to be that the ability to manipulate gravity would still require massive  amounts of energy to preform feats beyond keeping people on deck. Thanks again, I think this one is closed.

Comment: Hi Barry, your question has only been put on hold. That gives you the opportunity to edit it & ask the question you want to ask if you so wish. Glad you found the related questions & their answers helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, the energy requirements would not scale. One way to prevent in universe abuse is to increase the energy requirements with mass and distance and have it in an exponential fashion. You could store and release energy in a instant to jump, but artificial gravity would require power, over a long time. attracting say, a 300 kg creature to a nearby floor mounted gravity generator would be 'cheap'. Heck, you could use it to move cargo. As weight increases, power requirements increase, making gravity manipulation for permanent inter-spatial folds in space difficult.

A 'jump drive' may work in this fashion since it pinches space for a infinitesimally short period of time. However a snap-back effect might happen, with the potential of massive energy release or other side effects, depending on your universe